# Unable to get my bing translate api ajax call to work,

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, translation, bing-api

I am mock testing the Bing translate api, and attempting to do a very very basic translation of converting the innerHTML of a div into the specified languages. so pretty basic, but unable to find where my code is faltering...here is the jscript :

```
 var Translate={ 
  baseUrl:"http://api. 
    microsofttranslator.com/V2/Ajax.svc/", 
  appId:"7EE02F58CAC8EB2208D7AE8A194A43BB0C02436A", 
  translate:function(text,from,to, 
                              callback){ 
   var s = document.createElement("script"); 
   s.src =this.baseUrl+"/Translate"; 
   s.src +="?oncomplete="+callback;  
   s.src +="&appId="+this.appId; 
   s.src +="&from" + from ; 
   s.src += "&to=" + to ; 
   s.src += "&text=" + text;  
   document.getElementsByTagName( 
              "head")[0].appendChild(s); 
  } 
 } 
 var mycallback=function(result){ 
                         alert(result)}; 


function translater() 
{ 
 text = document.getElementById('translate').innerHTML; 

 alert(Translate.baseUrl);  

// Translate.translate("Hello World",              "en","es","mycallback"); 
}
```

As you can see from the above, I attempt to view what Translate.baseUrl looks like but nothing alerts itself....the html is :

```
<input type = "button" onclick = " translater()"/>
<div id ="translate"> This is the text to be translated. </div>
```

i cross tested if the onclick is working by putting in alert messages in the translater function and the callback happens on the onclick event.

Thanks guys!